# Soft Keyboard copies UI part

Tags: android

I am new to android and creating an registration form in app. When we click on edit text soft keyboard opens. but when keyboard opens it shows part of ui in keyboard suggestion. the image is below.

thanks in advance for any help.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]
The image link is below

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest file,add the following code to the activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add this line:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This will not push/cover your UI.